# DateTime conversion from string C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have a string (`642014`) which is in the format `Mdyyyy`.
I want to convert the string to `04062014`(`ddMMYYYY`).
I have tried the following code.
Please help.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("642014", "MMddyyyy",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out "04062014");
```

Comment: what will be the date for 1112014?

Comment: Try with `DateTime.TryParseExact("642014", "Mdyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
And remember import `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Perhaps you have confused `Mdyyy` and `MMddyyy`?

Comment: in other words how would your format differ 01/11/2014 from 11/01/2014?

Comment: And looks like you didn't understand how [`out` parameter modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/ee332485%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) works.

Comment: `out "04062014"` won't work. It's expected that you prepare a variable beforehand, like `DateTime parsedValue;`. Then, if the "try parsing" succeedes, `parsedValue` will contain the value you want. Now you can `ToString` it to any format you want.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a valid date format.

To highlight the issue is `1112014` the `1st of Nov` or `11th of Jan`?

If you have some sort of convention that allows you to determine which date it refers to in these instances you could do some sort of pre - processing or parse the string manually but you're not going to find anything 'built in' for that format

Answer (score 4):

Your situation looks like another *widest form* issue.

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **If you do not use date or time separators in a custom format pattern**,
>   use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest
>   form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to
>   specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of
>   the narrower form, "H".

Because of this, parsing strings without any date or time separator might be a problem sometimes.

For example let's talk about [`"d"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier). For formatting part, it formats your day part with a single digit *without* a leading zero. But for parsing, it *can* parse both `4` and `04` as well. It is the same as [`"M"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier). I don't say you should use `d` specifier for `04`. You *can*, but you shouldn't. You should always use the best formats that fits your string exactly.

Here is my opinion about what is going on here;

Because of the *widest form* rule, since your string doesn't have any date separator, you format should expect the widest forms of `d` and `M` which they are `dd` and `MM`. But I think these specifiers expect *with* a leading zero values (eg: `06` and `04`) when they used for single digits because **what actually they are for**. I couldn't find any evidence to support my theory but I am still investigating it.

I have a solution if your strings have *always* `Mdyyyy` format. Maybe it is not the best solution but I think it is useful if your strings have a constant format;

```
public static DateTime? ParseDate_Mdyyyy(string date)
{
    if (date == null)
        return null;
    if (date.Length < 6)
        return null;
    if (date.Length == 6)
        date = date.Insert(0, "0").Insert(2, "0");
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MMddyyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Now you can use this method as;

```
string s = "642014";
DateTime? date = ParseDate_Mdyyyy(s);
Console.WriteLine(date.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy")); // 04062014
```

I connected to .NET Framework Team about this problem here their response;

> Hi Soner,
>
> The parsing code is not really looking for any separator. Here is what
>   is going on:
>
> For the case of using `“MMddyyyy”`, the parsing starts in the method
>   [`DoStrictParse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/2558c4cbd566081b.html) which will call [`ParseByFormat`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/a6f76647667f9f16.html). This method will get the
>   first part of the format which is `“MM”` and then calls [`ParseDigits`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d4d260c649da51c1.html)  to
>   get the equivalent digits from the string we parse `“642014”` which will
>   give `“64”`. **Note that till that time there is no validation happen if
>   the number is out of range for the month in the selected calendar
>   (which is Gregorian in our case here)**. The parsing code will repeat
>   the same process for `“dd”` and will get equivalent part `“20”` and then
>   will repeat it for `“yyyy”` but this fail because it expect `4` digits and
>   we had only two (`“14”`).
>
> For the case of using `“Mdyyyy”`, it fails because almost same reason
>   when parsing the part `“M”` we know that the month can be `2` digits so
>   we’ll map it `“64”` and will do the same with `“d”` which map it to `“20”`
>   and then year will fail. I believe this is the reason the
>   documentation saying always use the widest form.
>
> **The recommendation here is** either to use the `2` digit forms in the
>   string like `"06042014"` and the parsing should succeed with `“MMddyyyy”`
>   and `“Mdyyyy”` too. other option is to insert separator `"6/4/2014"` or
>   `"06/04/2014"` and parse as `"M/d/yyyy"`
>
> Thanks, Tarek

Special thanks to; Tarek Mahmoud Sayed, Wes Haggard and Richard Lander.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here but... I think the `1112014` example in the comments and in my answer shows the crux of the OP's problematic format. Your own answer (despite the undoubted value it brings from your knowledge of the `.TryParseExact()` method's aim and implementation) doesn't really address this issue. In this example `date.Length == 7` so it misses all your pre-processing and still arrives at `.TryParseExact()` with the same ambiguity over whether it represents 1st Nov or 11th Jan

Comment: @Stewart_R Sorry but you are wrong. `1112014` doesn't show OP's problem. You say it will be `1st of Nov` or `11th of Jan`? You are right about `1112014` string but this doesn't effects `642014` string. Why? Because since OP parses this `MMddyyyy` format. We should say ok, `MM` parses `6` and `dd` parses `4` (even they are not for parsing single digits) and `yyyy` parses `2014`. Everything looks right. But it is not. Here we are facing `widest form` rule when string doesn't have a date separator as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Stewart_R ...My method is for only parsing string `Mdyyyy` format. It doesn't consider another formats. That's why I said _I have a solution if your strings have always Mdyyyy format_. Using wider specifiers is a rule, but they still expect the values what they are really for.

Answer (score -1):

To parse your string, first add slash to relevant positions then parse it

```
string str = "642014";
str = str.Insert(2,"/").Insert(1,"/"); 
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/d/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Stewart_R Sure it is. But this is what OP asking for