# Convert 14 number to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have a 14 number with 2 characters of AM/PM,
I want to convert them to dateTime

for example: `515201483742AM`

I tried this code:

```
DateTime result = 
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "Mdyyyyhmmsstt",
 CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

the output is error in format

where `515201483742AM` is `5 15 2014 8 37 42 AM`

month is `M` with no leading `0`

day also `d` no leading `0`

hours same and `tt` for `AM`

Comment: Not sure, but probably it is not possible to parse it with traditional Try/Parse methods. And also a custom parser will be really complex here. Can you ask for a less ambiguous input string?

Comment: Could you please provide the current date and time in your format? How would that look like?

Comment: I dare say it is impossible, e.g. if you had string starting with "115" there'd be no way of telling whether it's January 15th or November 5th.

Comment: So what time is `111201111111AM` in your format? Nov 11 1:11 AM? Jan 1 11:01 AM? If you need a compact time format, use some variant of ISO 8601 and keep the fields fixed: 20110111110100 is unambiguously 11 Jan 2011 11:01 (and 14 in length).

Comment: I think it cannot be done in any way, thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to parse your string without changing it because [`M` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#M_Specifier) *can* be two digits and it will map to parse `51` as a month. That's why your operation throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx). Same with [`h` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier).

That's why we need to change your string from `515201483742AM` to `05152014083742AM` to provide `M` format specifier will map `05` and `h` format specifier will map `08`.

You can use a method like<sup>1</sup>;

```
public static DateTime? ParseDate_Mdyyyyhmmsstt(string date)
{
    if (date == null)
        return null;
    if (date.Length < 14)
        return null;
    if (date.Length == 14)
        date = date.Insert(0, "0").Insert(8, "0");
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "Mdyyyyhmmsstt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
    return null;
}
```

And call it like;

```
var dt = ParseDate_Mdyyyyhmmsstt("515201483742AM");
Console.WriteLine(dt.Value); // 15.05.2014 08:37:42
```

<sup>1:</sup> I know this is not an *elegant* solution but it works in your case when your month and hour part is 1 digit.

Read: [DateTime conversion from string C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773534/datetime-conversion-from-string-c-sharp/26778076#26778076)

Comment: Sure, it works for this particular input, but for input `"1215201483742AM"` (which is 15.12.2014 08:37:52) it will return `null`...

Comment: @Grx70 Of course it will return `null` because `"1215201483742AM".Length` is `15`. That's why I said, **in your case**. For your example, OP can be skip `date.Insert(0, "0")` part because month part of your string is `2` digit but he still have to add `Insert(8, "0")` part because hour part is still `1` digit.

Comment: You're right, but given input of length 15 how can you tell whether you should skip `date.Insert(0, "0")` or `.Insert(8, "0")`?

Comment: @Grx70 I can't. No one can. OP is responsible to know what format of input will be in parsing operation, not me. I suggested to him as an answer specific format when month and hour part is 1 digit.

Comment: it is not fixed it there are many: these are some random values
 `1272014105547AM`-  `3252014113727AM` - `526201493920PM` - `9112014110901AM`

Comment: Also like Jeroen and Grx70 said up in the comments how it can be solved?

Comment: I think it cannot be done in any way, thanks guys for your help.

Comment: @M.Ghandour Yes, based your examples, it seems can not be done :(

Answer (score 0):

**use double "MM" and "dd" Instead of single "M" and "d"**

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"MMddyyyyhmmsstt",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

it will work.