# Short Time with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parsing, datetime

I’m trying to parse a time. I’ve seen this question asked/answered here many times but not for this specific scenario. Here’s my code:

```
var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("919", "Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also

```
var time2 = DateTime.ParseExact("919", "Hmm", null);
```

both of these throw the same

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

What I want is `9:19 AM`.

For further info I also need to parse `“1305”` as `1:05 PM`, this is working fine.

It seems to me I’m using the correct format. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure there *is* any format that can handle this. The problem is that "H" can be either one digit or two, so if there are two digits available, it will grab both - in this case parsing it as hour 91, which is clearly invalid.

Ideally, you'd change the format to `HHmm` - zero-padding the value where appropriate - so "0919" would parse fine. Alternatively, use a colon in the format, to distinguish between the hours and the minutes. I don't believe there's any way of making `DateTime` parse a value of "919" as you want it to... so you'll need to adjust the string *somehow* before parsing it. (We don't have enough context to recommend a particular way of doing that.)

Comment: Much appreciated for all the answers. I don’t have control of the text being created so the simplest solution for me seemed to be prefixing a zero as opposed to adding a colon in the middle.
    var text = "919";

    var time = DateTime.ParseExact(text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "Hmm", null);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your format is right but since [`H` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#H_Specifier) *might* be `2` character, `ParseExact` method try to parse `91` as an hour, which is an invalid hour, that's why you get `FormatException` in both case.

I connected to microsoft team about this situation 4 months ago. Take a look;

- [DateTime conversion from string C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773534/datetime-conversion-from-string-c-sharp/26778076#26778076)

They suggest to use 2 digit form in your string or insert a date separator between them.

```
var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("0919", "Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("9:19", "H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant exclude the `0` prefix to the hour. This works

```
var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("0919", "Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Perhaps you want to just prefix 3-character times with a leading zero before parsing.

Comment: Well you *can*, but only if you've got a separator. The problem is that there are two digits that can be parsed...

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciated for all the answers. I don’t have control of the text being created so the simplest solution for me seemed to be prefixing a zero as opposed to adding a colon in the middle.

```
var text = "919";

var time = DateTime.ParseExact(text.PadLeft(4, '0'), "Hmm", null);
```