# How to parse a string to DateTime with "yyyyMMdd Hmm" format?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I'm having huge problems with solving this problem. I'm trying to parse a string using Datetime.ParseExact().

I have the following code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20151210 832", "yyyyMMdd Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: String was not recognized as a
>   valid DateTime.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I can also get times like this:

```
00:01 => 1
01:00 => 1
01:10 => 10
```

Comment: Your update is not clear.Could you please add more information about the examples you've added.

Answer (score 5):

Since `H` specifier *can* be 2 digit, this method try to parse your `83` with `H` specifier. Since there is no such an hour, you get `FormatException`.

For your case, one way to prevent this is putting a leading zero just before your `8`.

```
var s = "20151210 832";
var result = s.Split(' ')[0] + " 0" + s.Split(' ')[1];
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "yyyyMMdd Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Be aware, this will *not* work for all cases. For example, if your hour part *already* two digit, if your single minute does not have leading zero.. etc.

Or you can put delimiter for your all parts but in such a case, you need to manipulate both your string and format.

[.NET Team suggest this way as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778076/447156).

Comment: @mrjasmin There is no format to parse your string _directly_. You need to manipulate your string.

Comment: @dotctor There are too many cases. If the hour part two digit, if the single minute part have or not leading zero.. You can't solve all of these with a _just_ one format. That's what I try to say.

Comment: Good explanation of the problem, but I have some comments: `mm` means that the minute part always has two digits so this comment `your single minutes have or nor leading zero` is irrelevant. `you need to manipulate both your string and format` - the format is specified only once for all cases and the string manipulation is necessary any way.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk You are correct. I changed _that_ sentence. What I try to say (I feel I couldn't explain myself clearly), this is a bad formatted `string` to parse `DateTime` (sorry OP but that's true). We can _not_ single minutes have leading zero or not for example. If input like `23`, what should we think? It is for only hours part as `23:00`? Is it for only minutes part as `00:23`? Or is it `2 hour and 3 minute` as `02:03`? That's impossible to know. That's why in my humble opinion, we _can_ generate only _specific_ solutions for _specific_ cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a separator before minutes (for example, a whitespace) and then you can parse it like this:

```
string example = "20151210 832";
example = example.Insert(example.Length - 2, " ");
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(example, "yyyyMMdd H mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I assume that the datetime string always contains two digits specifying minutes (check an article about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)). If my assumption is wrong then this string cannot be parsed.

Comment: As we discussed, _even_ adding whitespace does not solve _single digit without leading zero_ problem. For example if time part is `##83` (I used `#` instead of white space because if brokes `<code>` highlight), this will add white space before `8` not after and it will be like `  83`. I blame _the_ string for that, not us :)