# need to parse 7 digit string to date

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm working on a project where I need to ingest data from a flat file into the database.  My issue that I am having is that some of the date are not parsing correctly.  For example: 1977110 (yyyyMdd).

```
string dateString = "1977110";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMd", null); 
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

This will throw an exception: Unhandled exception.

> System.FormatException: String '' was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.    at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format,
> IFormatProvider provider)

I was expecting to parse the "1977110" string into date format of MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: What do you expect for October, November and December?

Comment: The problem is that your representation is ambiguous. 

"M" means month - so it will be 1 to 12. That said. 110 could be translated as November or January. (Either 10th of January or 0th of November)

Comment: That string format is inherently ambiguous.  The only reason we know that value is "January 10" is because there is no "November 0".  But what happens a day later?  Is that "January 11" or is it "November 1"?  The source of the string value may need to be cleaned up.

Comment: As the others said, your format seems ambiguous. But that's not the reason for failing. The string you are trying to parse has 7 characters, but your template only has 6. So per definition `ParseExact` will fail

Comment: I would suggest adding a check to the input date strings to make sure the length of the date string is 8 characters in length (YYYYMMdd)  and then use DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null);-- anything else should be rejected.

Comment: Fix your flat file to have an unambiguous 8-digit date, or write custom code to check the length and substring.

Comment: Some values are ambigious, e.g. `1977127` - either `7 Dec 1977` or `27 Jan 1977`

Comment: I would expect 01/10/1977

Comment: @RonOwens: And when the string is `"1977111"`, what date would that unambiguously represent and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic "wider form" situation on parsing operations in .NET.

Here what happens;

`1977` can be parsed with [`yyyy` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyyySpecifier) which is fine, [`M` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#month-m-format-specifier) is for `1` to `12`, that's why it takes `11` **not** just `1` as a "wider form" rule. But there is only `0` left in your string and it *can't* be parsed with [`d` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#day-d-format-specifier) because it's range is from `1` to `31`. That's why you get the exception.

I reached .NET Framework Team in the past with the same issue and their response was ["use the wider range form in your string or insert separator"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778076/447156). In both case, you *have to* manipulate your string to solve this ambiguity.

As a small suggestion, I wouldn't use `null` as an [`IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider) in a parsing operation because when you use null, the [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) is used of the machine you are running this code and this *can* be easily change over time. That's why it would be better to specify [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo) in your code.

As a final suggestion for your `date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` part. [`/` custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) as a special meaning as "*replace me current culture of supplied culture date separator*". Since you didn't provide any `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter in your `ToString` method, your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator) might be *different than* `/` and this code print that character, not `/`. Think about that.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to throw this back to the client to see if they can fix the dates.  other dates are they give have 8 digits.  They should be able to fix on their side.