# How convert a string into Datetime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to convert this string "12092014" into `DateTime` object as 12 `september` 2014.

Comment: Parse it using the `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Simple DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551283/parse-simple-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ddMMyyyy` is a standard date and time format of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) directly;

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("12092014");
```

If it is not, you can use [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "12092014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddMMyyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `TryParseExact` anyway - it says exactly what the OP is expecting.